# Appfuse Persistent Perm gen space

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, permgen, appfuse

I'm developing an application with appfuse. Everything is working well, but when i deploy it on Tomcat (6 and 7), i get the next error: Perm gen space.

I modified catalina.bat file adding this line:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

The webApp is working very fast, but after few clicks i get the error that i have commented before.
How can i avoid this??

**EDIT**

I'm usin appfuse 2.2.1

**EDIT 2**
The graph at top right show permGen use... is it normal?

[image]

**EDIT 3**

When Used memory == Max size in my dev enviroment this is what happens (but not in my production enviroment):

[image]

Dev enviroment:

Windows 7
 - jdk1.6
 - mysql 5.1
 - tomcat 6 - 7

Production enviroment:

Windows server 2008 
 - R2 ISAPI Filter to get working tomcat on IIS
 - Tested on Tomcat 6 and 7
 - Mysql 5.1 
 - jdk1.6

Memory profiler:

[image]